# Taking a 2 or more digit number as char in C

Tags: c

I have to write a program which takes a number as characters and then find its binary, so I used this code:

[screenshotofmycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vByYL.jpg)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    int operation,basetype,k=1,k2=1,binary=0,binary2=0,remainder,remainder2,binaryzero=0000;
    char num1,num2;
    printf("Please enter the number of the operation you would like to perform:");
    printf("\n1. Bitwise OR\n2. Bitwise NOT\n3. Bitwise COMPARE\n4. Exit");
    scanf("%d",&operation);
    if(operation==1){
    printf("You chose Bitwise OR operation.");
    printf("\nPlease enter the first number:");
    scanf(" %c",&num1);//*here i tried using %s also but it doesn't work for 2 
    // or more digit numbers..only for numbers from 0-9*//
    printf("Please specify the base(10/16):");
    scanf(" %d",&basetype);
    if(basetype==10){
        num1=num1-'0';//*changing from char to decimal*//
        if(num1==0){
            printf("\nYour first number is base 2 is %04d",binaryzero);
        }
        else if(num1>0){
                while(num1!=0){
                    remainder=num1%2;
                    num1=num1/2;
                    binary=remainder*k+binary;
                    k=k*10;
        }
    printf("Your first number in base 2 is:%04d",binary);
        }
        else{
            printf("WARNING: Your number is not valid in base 10!");
            printf("\nPlease enter the first number:");
            scanf(" %c",&num1);
        }


     }
       else if(basetype==16){
        if(num1==0){
            printf("\nYour first number in base 2 is %04d",binaryzero);
        }
        else if(num1>0 && num1<10 ){{
                while(num1!=0){
                    remainder=num1%2;
                    num1=num1/2;
                    binary=remainder*k+binary;
                    k=k*10;}
            }
            printf("\nYour first number in base 2 is %04d",binary);}
        else if(num1>='A' && num1<='F'){
                switch(num1){//*i will continue writing cases..*//
                    case 'A':printf("\nYour first number in base 2 is 1010",binary);}
                }
        }
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter the second number:");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("Please specify the base(10/16):");
    scanf("%d",&basetype);
    if(basetype==10){
    if(num2==0){

            printf("\nYour second number is base 2 is %04d",binaryzero);
        }
        else if(num2>0 && num2<10){
                while(num2!=0){
                    remainder2=num2%2;
                    num2=num2/2;
                    binary2=remainder2*k2+binary2;
                    k2=k2*10;
        }
    printf("Your second number in base 2 is:%04d",binary2);
        }
        else{
            printf("WARNING: Your number is not valid in base 10!");
            printf("\nPlease enter the second number:");
            scanf("%d",&num2);

    }}
    return 0;

}
```

Unfortunately, it only works for numbers from 0 to 9, but it should work on 2 or more digit numbers.
I have to take the number as char because the user might enter the number in base 16 and I have to ask the number first then the base type. We are not allowed to use arrays.

Comment: Post the code as text right here.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::stoi`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and solutions to your question may differ. Please select one language; I'd suggest `C` according to the style of the code in the screenshot.

Comment: i added my code as a text... i don't know how to use std::string and std::stoi

the language should be c not c++

thanks in advanced

Comment: `We are not allowed to use arrays` -- Huh?

Comment: Please learn to indent the code systematically.  There are some curious constructs in there, notably `else if(num1>0 && num1<10 ){{
                while(num1!=0){`  It is very seldom — I'd argue 'never' — necessary to use two open braces like that in normal C code.  Putting two `}}` on a single line is also extremely dubious formatting.

Comment: yes it's an assignment for school and we are not allowed to use arrays....

Comment: @AslıKırmızı - have a look at `strtol` it will take the numeric BASE as an argument for converting a string to a number -- very helpful in cases like this. (it's in `stdlib.h`) Alternatively you could have the user enter base 16 numbers in the format `0x...` and check for `0x` in the input.

Comment: Start from the top. You declared `num1` to be `char`. How do you expect it to accept a two-digit number, or ANY string of length greater than 1?

Comment: What should i declare num1 as? I cant use arrayss

Comment: @mathguy You don't know how numbers are stored.

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
     char num1;
     scanf(" %c",&num1);
     while(num1!=10){
      printf("%c",num1);
      scanf("%c",&num1);
     }
 
     return 0;
    }`

I use this code to be able to print all characters entered. For example when i enter HELLO, the output is HELLO.. but i want to store this output as one variabla (like word=HELLO). Anyone knows what can i do? @nicomp @JonathanLeffler @DavidC.Rankin @HappyGreenKidNaps @charles

Comment: @AslıKırmızı - "takes a number as characters" and "cannot use arrays" pretty much excludes numbers of more than one digit. I would ask the teacher to explain the assignment since this seems to contradict itself.

Comment: @nicomp - care to elaborate? Why do I even care how numbers are **stored**? My point was that a `char` variable is one byte - if the input is to be "as chars" and "we can't use arrays", how will the input be passed to the function?

Comment: @mathguy You can store 2 digits in one byte.

Comment: @nicomp - I can, but that is not the issue. You can **not** store two **characters** in one byte. But this is a dumb discussion anyway; the title itself says "2 **or more** digit number." I wasn't sure if you actually had a point, but it is clear you don't.

Comment: @mathguy Sadly it's clear you don't understand the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `atoi()` function

First include `string.h`
then do this

```
char arr[3];
scanf("%s",arr);
int num=atoi(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for your 2-digit number:

```
num1=num1-'0';
```

Comment: so what should i do? :(